How do we know the next number to appear at least six times in Pascal's triangle is 61218182743304701891431482520?
I have been doing research on Singmaster's conjecture, which deals with the number of times a value in Pascal's triangle appears. I was looking at the Wikipedia article, and it states that the next number to appear at least six times is 61218182743304701891431482520. Is there a proof of this somewhere? There is a reference number tagged to it, but I looked at the link and didn't see anything about 61218182743304701891431482520. If you know of a proof, please link me. To be clear of what I'm asking, how do we know there isn't a number between 24310 and 61218182743304701891431482520 that doesn't appear at least six times? Is there a proof, or was it computation of each number in between?

If you read carefully, it's the next number after $24310$ "in Singmaster's infinite family (given in terms of Fibonacci numbers)". So it's just the next number in the set generated by the formulas that were given in the previous section in terms of Fibonacci numbers. I don't see anywhere where it is said that there are no other smaller numbers that appear six times; all it says is that if such numbers exist, they don't follow the formulas. There's a footnote to an on-line PDF in the Wikipedia article; I suggest looking at that.

(This was a comment but may be about as much of an answer as this question can get, so I'm reposting it here with a few edits. The only significant addition is that I glanced at the cited PDF myself.)
If you read the Wikipedia article carefully, $61218182743304701891431482520$ is the next number after $24310$ "in Singmaster's infinite family (given in terms of Fibonacci numbers)". So it's just the next number in the set generated by the formulas that were given in the previous section in terms of Fibonacci numbers. I don't see anywhere where Wikipedia says that there are no other smaller numbers that appear six times; all it says is that if such numbers exist, they don't follow the formulas.
There's a footnote leading to
an on-line PDF
in the Wikipedia article; I suggest looking at that.
The authors describe a computer-aided search that may answer your question more completely.

Thank you for this. I guess I didn't quite understand the Wikipedia article upon first read. But thank you for pointing this out. I'm just wondering if there are any numbers in between that appear as many times but don't equate to the equations given by Singmaster.

That's also a good question and it seems that the PDF that I linked to may have an answer to it. That is, they mention something about having done an exhaustive search on a computer (I didn't read it thoroughly enough to understand how they did it) and it seems like they might have found there were no other numbers in between at least those two Singmaster numbers. So I definitely recommend reading that article.

I actually created a computer program to do an exhaustive search and none were found. But that doesn't mean none exist between 61218182743304701891431482520 and the next in Singmaster's family. In fact, I came up with an algorithm that minimizes the amount of numbers to check to determine if any multiples of $n$ exist for any given $n$.

That sounds like something worth documenting somewhere. I don't know what advice to give about actually doing so, but maybe something in arxiv. If you do write it up you should cite the linked PDF since you either added information to it or independently confirmed one of their results.
